# Where is the CMake GUI for Linux?

Tags: ubuntu, cmake, cmake-gui

I have CMake installed on my Ubuntu Linux. Trying to run CMake GUI in Linux. I found it works in Windows, but where to get it and how to run in Linux?

Comment: did you install `cmake-gui`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`cmake` is documented (type `man cmake` and see also [cmake.org](https://cmake.org/)) as being a command, so it should not have any GUI interface:

> DESCRIPTION

> ```
>   The  "cmake" executable is the CMake command-line interface.  It may be
> ```

```
   used to configure projects in scripts.  Project configuration  settings
   may be specified on the command line with the -D option.
```

And it is just generating a `Makefile` (to be used by the [`make` command](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/)). I don't understand what kind of GUI are you expecting.

On Debian and derivatives like Ubuntu, you might install the `cmake-gui` or `cmake-qt-gui` package then run the `cmake-gui` command.

And `make` is often running [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/). Try `make -p` to understand the default rules of GNU make... So read documentation of GNU make and [of GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/) (and probably of [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)).

Comment: sudo apt install cmake-qt-gui

Comment: `sudo apt install cmake-gui` also work, on Ubuntu 16.04 it installs the cmake-qt-gui package.

Answer (score 20):

**Update**:
As of CMake 3.7.2, cmake-gui is still not built by default, but can easily be added to the build by specifying one additional flag. Qt is still required, I am using 4.8 but I'm sure other versions will work fine.

Download the source from the website, extract to a directory of your choosing, then run the following at the commmand line:

- ./bootstrap --qt-gui
- gmake
- gmake install (optional - don't forget sudo if you need it)

Hey presto! cmake-gui is now present in the bin directory along with the other tools.

Note: if the build process fails in some way, just check the error message and work with it! There are too many pre-requisites and variables, attempting to detail them all would make the post tl;dr and would be out of date before being submitted (see one of the other posts for an example of this).

---

Basic installation for CMake

Under linux it comes with the default installation from the cmake website (at least for version 3.5.1)

It is installed in the same place as cmake, which on my machine is:

```
/usr/local/bin/cmake-gui
```

I built my cmake from source and by default, cmake-gui does not get built. To add as a target, the following variable must be set:

```
BUILD_QtDialog
```

eg. SET(BUILD_QtDialog TRUE) should do it

Note: cmake-gui is based on Qt so you must have Qt installed if you want to build it.

Comment: Where do you put the "SET(BUILD_QtDialog TRUE)" ??

Answer (score 13):

For Ubuntu (and I guess for more linux versions):

```
 sudo apt-get install cmake-qt-gui
```

Can be started after installation as *cmake-gui* or by using the ubuntu GUI (just type cmake and it will show the typical cmake-gui-icon)

Answer (score 8):

**`ccmake` curses UI**

```
sudo apt-get install cmake-curses-gui
cd build
ccmake ..
```

Then:

- edit your options
- hit `c` to update the cache
- `q` to exit

And now you can `make` again with the new variables.

[image]

Tested in Ubuntu 16.10, cmake 3.5.2.

Comment: Your screenshot says `c` to configure, not to update the cache

Comment: @Cœur I'm not that fluent in cmake, isn't the cmake configuration stored in the `CMakeCache` file, which I refer to as just "cache"?

Answer (score 4):

If you're building the latest from source, this is a lot harder than anyone else here suggests.  I finally found [this](http://embedonix.com/articles/linux/installing-cmake-3-5-2-on-ubuntu) that got it working:

> First, download the source from: https://cmake.org/download/
>
> More specifically for Ubuntu 14.04 or higher, 64 bit get:
>   https://cmake.org/files/v3.5/cmake-3.5.2.tar.gz
>
> Download it to the following directory (or any directory you like!): 
>   **/opt/dev-tools-sources**
>
> Unzip it there, using GUI archive manager or **`$ tar -zxvf cmake-3.5.2.tar.gz`**
>
> You should have now a folder like this: **/opt/dev-tools-sources/cmake-3.5.2**

---

> Go to this folder: **`$ cd /opt/dev-tools-sources/cmake-3.5.2`**
>
> Install **openssl** to allow CMAKE have access to ssl protected websites
>   if it needs to download extra files **`$ sudo apt install openssl libssl-dev`**
>
> Edit the bootstrap file and change the line:
>   `cmake_options="-DCMAKE_BOOTSTRAP=1"`
>
> To this `cmake_options="-DCMAKE_BOOTSTRAP=1 -DCMAKE_USE_OPENSSL=ON"`
>
> If you want cmake-gui, you will need qt4 libs an ncurses 
>   **`$ sudo apt install libqt4-dev qt4-dev-tools libncurses5-dev`**
>
> Run the configuration (you need to have gcc and g++ 4.7 or higher
>   installed. I recommend 4.8.4 or higher actually!) 
>   **`$ ./configure --qt-gui`**

---

> Make sure in the generated **CMakeCache.txt**, GUI is set to TRUE, open **CMakeCache.txt** with any editor and check the following line:
>   `BUILD_QtDialog:BOOL=ON`
>
> If it was `OFF` or `0`, make it `ON` or `1`

---

> It is time to build executables and libraries from source: **`$ make -j2`**
>
> Now, install: **`$ sudo make install`**
>
> Confirm you also got GUI version with **`$ cmake-gui`**

Answer (score 0):

I also faced a similar problem. I did something like:

1. Open https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/cmake-qt-gui/ and click available on the software centre.
2. new window opens and click install
3. write cmake-gui on terminal

and it solved my problem.