# Using cmake: General use of directories and especially default location of output binaries

Tags: cmake

**1) When using cmake, is there a standard way to make the binaries be put in `/usr/local/bin`?**

---

I'm trying to better understand cmake, especially the major phases, which I think are configure, make, and install.

I want to better understand which directories are used by default and why, for these:

- **source** - code and other source files,
- **build** - scratch pad or working directory
- **binary** - for newly created binaries
- **other** - for things like man pages

---

I'm pretty new to Linux and started by making a fresh version of cmake, (*which I need to use for another project*), as follows:

- Download cmake's source file: `cmake-3.6.2.tar.gz` from [here](https://cmake.org/download/).
- Put it's contents into `/usr/local/src/cmake-3.6.2`, (Debian Jessie).
- Then run `sudo ./configure`, `sudo make` and finally `sudo make install`.

**By default it seemed to:**

- **Read** source from the place you explicitly tell it, e.g. `cd /usr/local/src/project; cmake .`
- **Use** `/usr/local/src/cmake-3.6.2` as it's working build directory, (perhaps because it was the current directory in step 1), creating many new directories and files there, and
- **Create** its new executables in: `/usr/local/src/cmake-3.6.2/bin`

---

**So I'm confused.**  I would have thought that by default a `sudo install` would have installed cmake in such a way into my system as to make it generally visible anywhere.

---

**???** I'm not sure, but think the best way to make system resources visible is to either 1) locate the binaries, or 2) soft links to them, in folders somewhere in the standard `PATH`.  In other words, don't extend PATH with each and every new set of binaries.

Is it possible to have cmake put the binaries in `/usr/local/bin` by default?

---

**Yes I can make manual bin links:**

I'm not asking this question because making these links is hard, but because I think I might be missing something that just does this without me having to.  Also bin files are just one of the outputs.  There are also things like man pages and how do those get hooked up?

- My standard path is `.:/home/<myusername>/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin`.
- So I created links in `/usr/local/bin` pointing to these executables (using 
  `cd /usr/local/bin; ln -s ../src/cmake-3.6.2/bin/*`).
- Now I can run `cmake --version` from anywhere.

**I can also see that cmake uses two main directories**

- I noticing that cmake had not, by default, built the gui tool, so I found instructions (ref [page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40252960/1483904)) and built the gui tool, (and as above created a link to use it from within my standard path).
- Then I opened the GUI tool and tried to re-make cmake.
- It asks you for a source and "build" directory:

[image]

But this is confusing because the "..build the binaries.." directory you give can:

1) Overlap the source directory in which case it merges lots of new files and folders into it, or

2) If set to something like `/usr/local/bin` fills that with a bunch of junk which includes a secondary `/bin` with the actual binaries, or

3) If set to some other location like possibly `/usr/local/projectname/output`, still does not put the output binaries where they can automatically be used.

**Is there a standard way to make the binaries be put in `/usr/local/bin` ?, (i.e. that my PATH will automatically pick up) or failing that, is the any simple and direct way to do this?**

---

**Tip:**

- [This](https://cmake.org/download/) is a good talk introducing cmake.

Comment: That by far to many question in one question.

Comment: I'm really just asking 1 question.  The most obvious things are not so obvious to the new person, so I thought some context, and a common example, might be appropriate.  Perhaps I should ask this elsewhere.

Comment: You seem to be really confused. Why the cmake executable the source bin? Project below `/usr/local/`? Maybe you make a tutorial for CMake. Then you can post a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Build** directory *is UNRELATED* to the place, where deliverable files will be **installed**.

**Build** directory is a working directory, where compiler, linker and other tools *generate* deliverable files with some other auxiliary files. E.g., object files (`.o`) are auxiliary files: they are produced by compiler, used by the linker and are never installed. Also, build directory contains `Makefile`s and some other files, used by `make`.

When **install** files, `make install` takes deliverable files *from build* directory, and place them into their *final locations*. After that project is ready for use, and build directory can be removed.

Place, where deliverable files are *installed*, is controlled by variable

> *CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX*

which you can set in cmake gui tool after the first configuration occures. Normally, binary files are installed into `bin/` subdirectory relative to that prefix, so you may set *CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX* to `/usr/local` for get executables being installed into `/usr/local/bin/`.

As for build directory, you may create it *anywhere*. Usually, it is created in the directory where user has write access, so neither configuration nor build requires root priveleges. E.g., you may choose `/home/<user>/cmake-build`.